# Pass hidden field tag params with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

From the`views/plans/new.html.erb` I get the plan_id and price params with the following:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_store_registration_path(:plan_id => plan.id, :price => plan.price) %>
```

Then the app redirects to the sign-up page and with the following I keep the previous params and add the email as well:

registrations_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
end
```

Finally after sign-up, the app redirects to the views/transcation/new.html.erb, which has the `plan_id`, `price`and `email` params.

```
Parameters: {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
```

At this point I'm trying to pass the email param to the transaction with `<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>`

But not getting an email as you can see in the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KeS2xK7NIJZwFQvW2kJKupcpURnQweq+yoRgk9AJ1aaOgFIIym4RKadI4jc6vYynMo4vKR4eLmdIynfBG+EusQ==", "email"=>"", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "amount"=>"150.0", "payment_method_nonce"=>"0c22f2fa-e212-0ad3-753b-0d183d02522b"}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong???

***Update1***

Inside the views/transcation/new.html.erb there is the braintree drop in ui and the script along with the three hidden fields:

```
<div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
      <div id="dropin"></div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, params["plan_id"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:amount, params["price"]) %>
      <%=submit_tag "Pay #{params["price"]}$", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<script>
    braintree.setup("<%=@client_token%>", 'dropin', {
        container: 'dropin'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have another field in that form that has the name "email"? If `params['email']` is making it that far, and you can see the value in the hidden field when you inspect the page it should be submitted...however, if rails comes across the same name multiple times when parsing, it uses the last one it encounters (exceptions for array parameters)

Comment: can you share contents of views/transcation/new.html.erb?

Comment: @ Satishakumar Awati please check update 1 for more details!

Comment: You should not rely on a value of an hidden field tag (which can be easily changed by the end-user) but instead use what you can fetch from your database. As you said, the end-user is asked to sign-up and then redirected to a place where you want to use these hidden_field_tag. Maybe you can use a record, like `Plan`, to determine what is the price and email values? Because with this code, any end-user can edit the HTML and change the price and/or email of the transaction

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Simple Lime, no I don't have another email field in that form!! I have upload the views/transcation/new.html.erb... please check update 1 for more details!

Answer (score 5):

Please set the value of hidden field like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => "test@test.com" %>
```

or

```
<%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => @object.email %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Yogesh Waghmare... thi first one returns the email test@test.com and if I use the second one`<%= hidden_field :email, :value => @store.email %>` it returns `undefined method email for nil:NilClass`.. both of them without the f.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have not confused.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "email", params[:email] %>
```

`hidden_field_tag` used with [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

```
<%= f.hidden_field "email", params[:email] %>
```

and `f.hidden_field` is used with [form_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: @ Satishakumar Awatii please check update 1 for more details!

Answer (score 0):

There are Two tags for add Hidden fields in ruby on rails view

1. [hidden_field](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002295)
2. [hidden_field_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002252)

> Form for rails view with hidden fields

`<% form_for(:request, :url => requests_path) do |f| %>`

```
`<div class="actions">`
    <%= f.hidden_field :column_name %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected', 'column_name' %>
    <%= f.submit e %>
</div>
```

<% end %>`

> Controller code:

```
 params[:selected]="column_name"
 params[:request][:column_name] = request.column_name
```

> When we used f.hidden_field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :column_name %>
```

> it change to html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="request_column_name" name="request[column_name]" value="#{@request.column_name}" />
```

> and when we used hidden_field_tag

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'selected', 'column_name' %>
```

> it change to html:

```
<input id="selected" name="selected" type="hidden" value="none"/>
```

> And we can send a custom value as a hidden input for your model like that:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :model_field_name, value: 12 %>
```