# Hidden field tag value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

From the`views/plans/new.html.erb` I get the plan_id and price params with the following:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_store_registration_path(:plan_id => plan.id, :price => plan.price) %>
```

Then the app redirects to the sign-up page and with the methods `def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)` and `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` I keep the previous params and merge the email param:

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Stores::RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   def new
     build_resource({})
     resource.build_account
     respond_with self.resource
     session[:registration_params] = request.query_parameters
   end


   def create
     build_resource(sign_up_params)
     resource.save
     yield resource if block_given?
     if resource.persisted?
       if resource.active_for_authentication?
         flash[:notice] = 'Successfully signed up'
         respond_with resource, location:   after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
         flash[:notice] = "Signed up but #{resource.inactive_message}"
     expire_data_after_sign_in!
     respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
     end
   end


   def edit
     super
   end


   def update
     super
   end


    def destroy
     super
    end

    def cancel
     super
    end

  protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
           :account_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :buisness_name,
                                   :buisness_description, :web_site, :phone_number,
                                   :street, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country])
    }
  end


  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_transaction_path(resource,  session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
  end

   def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     new_transaction_path(resource, session[:registration_params].merge(ema‌​il: resource.email))
   end
end
```

After submit sign-up, the app redirects to the views/transcation/new.html.erb, which has the `plan_id`, `price`and `email` params.

```
 Parameters: {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0"}
```

And the url shows:

```
http://localhost:3000/transactions/new.1?ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=example%40gmail.com&plan_id=bs96&price=150.0
```

Inside the views/transcation/new.html.erb there is the braintree drop in ui and the script along with the three hidden fields:

```
<div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
      <div id="dropin"></div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, params["plan_id"]) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:amount, params["price"]) %>
      <%=submit_tag "Pay #{params["price"]}$", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<script>
    braintree.setup("<%=@client_token%>", 'dropin', {
        container: 'dropin'
    });
</script>
```

At this point I'm trying to keep the email param to the transaction with
`<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>`

But if I click submit i'm not getting an email as you can see in the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KeS2xK7NIJZwFQvW2kJKupcpURnQweq+yoRgk9AJ1aaOgFIIym4RKadI4jc6vYynMo4vKR4eLmdIynfBG+EusQ==", "email"=>"", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "amount"=>"150.0", "payment_method_nonce"=>"0c22f2fa-e212-0ad3-753b-0d183d02522b"}
```

If I inspect the params inside the views/transcation/new.html.erb with this     `<%= params.inspect %>` it prints out this: `<ActionController::Parameters {"ema‌​il"=>"example@gmail.com", "plan_id"=>"bs96", "price"=>"150.0", "controller"=>"transactions", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>`

And this `<%= params[:email].inspect %>` returns `nil`

Any ideas why I can't get the email param?

Comment: is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568785/pass-hidden-field-tag-params-with-rails-5

Comment: If you print the params["email"] in the form is there any value?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anton... `<%= params["email"].inspect %>` this returns nil... But this `<%= params.inspect %>` returns the email along with all the other params

Comment: Can you post the params as they are inside the form?

Comment: @Anton, please check update1

Answer (score 0):

You are merging the params into session[:registration_params] and than trying to fetch them into the query string params. You could just fetch those parameters from the session inside the transactions controller and delete them after successful save.

Comment: hmmmm... It returns `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

Comment: ok :) Please print out the entire params within the form and post it.

Comment: Can you path to the new_transaction_path only the email and check out the url if it is in the query string?

Comment: new_transaction_path(ema‌​il: resource.email) - this one

Comment: I get this at the url `http://localhost:3000/transactions/new?ema%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bil=last2%40gmail.com&plan_id=bs96&price=150.0`

Comment: So the params["email"] is not nil now?

Comment: The inspect still prints out nil, but the url shows the above.. weird

Comment: it works if I pass only the (email: resource.email), but I need the other registration_params as well.

Comment: Hi, can you print the session[:registration_params]? And why are you fetching it from the session?

Comment: I updated the entire questioning order to make more sense as to what I'm doing.

Comment: In order to keep the url params before registration, I'm adding parameters in a query string to a path the new_store_registration.Please check out the def new at registration_controller.rb

Comment: Ok so if you store the params in session why don't you just fetch them on transactions controller from the session as well?